# JSON value replacement by DataGen

Tags: java, json, placeholder

Hi StackOverflow Users,

I'm having a following JSON either as JSONObject or String

```
   {
     "canconnect" : true,
     "NetworkData": {
        "mac": "{MAC}",
        "ipaddress": "{IP}"
     }
   }
```

Here {MAC} and {IP} are kind of PlaceHolder. Once the data for {MAC} and {IP} available from datasource then I need to replace the place holder with proper values using Java.

This is pretty much equivalent to "PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" in SpringFramework but for Json.

Thanks In Advance,
Arun.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 1):

This is as easy as using the replace method of the String class. You should read documentation before asking. Example of its usage:

```
String aux = "{\"canconnect\" : true, \"NetworkData\": {\"mac\": \"{MAC}\", \"ipaddress\": \"{IP}\"}}";
System.out.println(aux.replace("{MAC}", "YOUR_MAC").replace("{IP}", "YOUR_IP"));
```

Comment: I know string replacement will do, but there cases where the 1st occurrence of "{MAC}" will get different value than  the 2nd occurrence of {MAC}, so thinking is there is any framework that can do the job.

Comment: That is not a problem since you have different signatures for replacement. You hava replace(String str1, String str2), replaceFirst(String str1, String str2) and replaceAll(String str1, String str2). If you need to replace one by one you can always use replaceFirst. @user1316830